# My Java thread stops at "OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());" w/o any error?

Tags: multithreading, url, outputstream, urlconnection

So I am currently writing a program used to access a website and retrieve information.
The functional part of the program lies as follows:

```
URL url = new URL("website name");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
```

I am trying to use threads to implement this program, so that each new thread created will open up a new connection. I have already tested this program separately from a thread and this code works perfectly fine, but the moment that place this code into the run() method of my Thread class, it stops working.
I placed print statements after every single line of code, to give me an idea as to where the program was stopping and the last sign of life is consistently "setDoOutput(true)" and nothing happens after that. No errors, no nothing, the program just stops.
What is going on?

Comment: you should provide the thread launching code too. Meanwhile, is this in the context of an ejb / EE server? There may be thread policies and permissions interfering.

Comment: also note that you are trying to POST by setting the setDoOutput(), so what are you posting, how do you know this works in another thread? which thread?